# REST API for sharing Files

Tags: c#, rest, microservices, restful-architecture

i would like to share files from a microservice. I have now some personal trouble during the feature to share files - especially PDF Files.

Option one i thought about is to deserialize the file and send the binaries in the http response message.

Option two is about the sharing from an link. The link will guide the user into an folder which is located in the microservice location.

Are there more options to handle this problem or which possibilities do you prefer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used is to build a SocketListener and encode the file content in UTF-8 and write them to the http response. It's easier than your option two, personally speaking.